# Why does sorting the array like this not work?

Tags: arrays, swift

```
struct Home {
var street:String
var number:Int
}

func getHouse() -> [Home] {
var house = [Home]()

let house1 = Home(street: "Jacob Street", number: 26)
house.append(house1)

let house2 = Home(street: "High Road", number: 58)
house.append(house2)

let house3 = Home(street: "Zebra Close", number: 12)
house.append(house3)

return house
}

var houses = [Home]()
houses = getHouse()

houses.sort({$0.street < $1.street })

for i in 0..<houses.count {

print("\(houses[i].street)")
}
```

I'm trying to sort them alphabetically by street in this example, or possibly by number if needed.  They still seem to stay in the order I've put them in rather than being in alphabetical order which i want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `sort` returns a new array, but you're not doing anything with the result. You can either do

```
let sortedHouses = houses.sort {$0.street < $1.street }
```

or

```
houses.sortInPlace {$0.street < $1.street }
```

Answer (score 2):

You might use `sortInPlace()`,

`sort()` returns a new sorted object and leaves the receiver unchanged.

Or

```
let sortedHouses = houses.sort {$0.street < $1.street }
```